# Issued a public address and private key in 2018

Tags: xlm, wallets

I was generated 2 key pairs (public addresses and private keys) for 2 XLM addresses back in 2018 on Stellar Account Viewer.  I only funded one of those public addresses with about 100 XLM.  I did not fund the other public address as of today.  When I look up the other public address which I did not fund the results come back as address not found, couldn't find or no results on any of the Stellar Explorers. Is that happening because it was never funded?  I still have all the info provided to me from 2018.

Answer (score 1):

You created keys but not an account.

To create an account you must fund the private/public keypair you generated.
Thus, the block explorers will return an account not found error.